# when is the pullback along the shift (decalage) morphism a direct product, in sSets

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-categories

What is the meaning of the following condition on a morphism in sSets
or simplicial topological spaces:

> a morphism becomes a direct product after the pullback along
> the shift(decalage) morphism  ?

Is it related to being locally trivial ? Is such a morphism necessarily a fibration (say provided the base is fibrant; I understand the decalage morphism is a fibration under this assumption.) ?

Let me explain this in notation. Let $[+1]:\Delta\to \Delta$ be the endomorphism of $\Delta$, $[+1](n):=1+n$
adding a new least element, and for a simplicial set $B$ let $B\circ [+1] \to B$
be the shift(decalage) morphism "forgetting the first coordinate".
Let $f:X\to B$ be a morphism in sSets.

> What is the meaning of the condition that $B\circ [+1]\times_B X \to B\circ [+1]$ is a direct product, i.e. there is $F$ and an isomorphism  $B\circ [+1]\times F \approx B\circ[+1]\times_B X$ over $B\circ [+1]$?

I understand that if $B$ is fibrant, then $B\circ [+1]\to B$ is a fibration, and if $F$ is fibrant, the map $B\circ[+1]\times F\to B\circ [+1]$ is a fibration, and so perhaps $X\to B$ would also be a fibration in this case ?

Any references would be appreciated.

Motivation. There is a well-known anology between $B\circ [+1]$ and the path space of $B$ of a topological space. If one considers this property in the category of topological spaces and replaces $B\circ [+1]$ by the path space,
I think this property defines a map being *locally trivial*.

This property also defines a map being locally trivial if interpreted in a certain simplicial category containing the topological spaces (the category of simplicial filters).

Comment: On the face of it, this seems like a very strange property for a map $f: X \to B$ to have. What's an example where this happens? Note that $B\circ [+1]$ is weakly contractible. In good cases ( maybe when $B$ is a Kan complex?) $B \circ [+1] \to B$ is a fibration, so your pullback should model the fiber of $f: X \to B$. The condition that your pullback splits as a product is always true up to homotopy (since $B \circ [+1]$ is contractible).

Comment: You mean to say that $ B\circ [+1]$ is _a disjoint union_ of weakly contractible sets, but that does not affect the argument. A motivation for the question is that if instead of $B\circ [+1]$ we consider the path space and instead of sSets the category of topological spaces, this gives the definition of being _locally  trivial_. Considering the pullback being a product up to homotopy would make the condition trivial in this case. I am adding this to the question.